# Send sounds from 2 programs to 2 different jack outputs

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, headphones

Here is my setup: 
- My sound card has several jack outputs (2 green, 1 blue and 1 black).
- I have 2 devices that makes sound: a headphones and speakers.
- I'm running Windows 7

My problem is as follow:
I would like to plug my speakers and headphones on 2 different jacks from my sound card and be able to:
- send the sound from (almost) every programs to my headphones
- send the sound from specific programs to my speakers (like ambient music).

How can I achieve this, if possible? (but I believe it is because some DJ programs can use several jack outputs. Like one for the real music people and one for the preview for the DJ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does not provide a built in means of directing audio output from multiple applications to different outputs.  It is possible to accomplish this if the software is written to support outputting audio to outputs other than the default.  Unfortunately, most software applications just stream to the current default audio output as currently set up in Windows.

Comment: What about a driver?

Comment: There may be a software utility or driver out there that will allow it, but I am not aware of one.